# Facing issue to add new server in pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am new to `Postgres` and `pgadmin4`. I am trying to add a new server in `pgadmin4` but I get the following error

Unable to connect to server:

> FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

I have followed different methods to create role and user using psql commands but had no luck to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance,

Aisha

Comment: can you enter to the server by psql?

Comment: yes I can enter in Postgres by using terminal

Comment: Then, inside psql run the comand  `\du`, this will list the users. See if there is the user postgres, since that is the error message. **Note:** first run `psql` from the terminal to enter psql monitor, it automatically will open postgres database where you run the command `\du`.